# Drive custom SKAction with SKKeyFrameSequence values, how?

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, skaction, skkeyframesequence

For motion to be done by a custom SKAction, I want a much stronger ease type than is possible with traditional equation created curves.

**How do I use an SKKeyFrameSequence to drive animation in a SKAction?**

SKKeyFrameSequence creates the type of curve I want, like so:

```
let sequence = SKKeyframeSequence(
    keyframeValues: [0.00, 0.05, 0.25, 0.70, 0.85, 0.95, 0.98, 1.00],
    times:          [0.00, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.23, 0.28, 0.50, 1.00])

sequence.interpolationMode = .spline
stride(from: 0.00, to: 1.00, by: 0.025).forEach {
let value = sequence.sample(atTime: CGFloat($0))
```

This looks like this, on a curve created in PlayGrounds:

[image]

SKActions, the custom type, take in the elapsed time and the Node to apply changes to.

But I cannot conceive how to take SKKeyFrameSequence values and get them into the custom SKAction to transform the position, rotation or scale of the Node the custom Action is being run upon.

SK Custom Action Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417745-customaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a custom action, it looks like you pass a block which sets the position to `customAction(withDuration:actionBlock)`:

```
let action = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: duration) { node, elapsed in
    node.position.x = sequence.sample(atTime: elapsed/duration)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I've over done the simplicity of the example... if the duration is not 1 second (say 2 seconds) how would that be handled?

Comment: Argh, brilliant. Does this mean `duration` is within the scope of the closure? I was afraid it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Confused Hmm?  The closure will capture `duration`, so if you can access it outside of the closure, you can access it inside of the closure.

Comment: This, if it works, is far better than I thought it would be, and vastly easier. THANK YOU!

Comment: Tested... IT WORKS!